# Returning "application defined or object defined error" and "Type Mismatch" in vlookup in VBA script

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, vlookup

I'm having some problems with the vba script below. It's pretty simple.  It's meant to take the value of a dropdown list and respond based on a yes/no/null value in another sheet.  The code works fine, except for that there is a problem in the vlookup lines that stops the script from running.

The first two vlookup lines return an "application defined or object defined error", and the third returns a "Data type mismatch" error.  Each of the cells that the formulas refer to are formatted as text, so I'm not sure what the problem is...  Any feedback would very helpful.  Thank you!

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("countryProductCell")) Is Nothing Then
    lastcolumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    cellRow = Target.Row
    defaultCellColumn = 4
    Dim countryIndex As Variant
    countryIndex = Array(6, 6, 30, 21, 35, 29, 32, 20, 23, 18, 19, 34, 33, 22, 31, 26, 25, 27, 28, 7, 8, 15, 12, 10, 13, 11, 16, 17, 9)
    i = 0
    For Each countryCell In Range(Cells(cellRow, 5), Cells(cellRow, lastcolumn))
        'If Default is selected
        'If Not Target.Value = "(Select Title)" Then
            'If Product is not selected
            If countryCell.Value = "Use Default" Then
               'Look Up Purchaseablility, Needs Array
                If Not Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(cellRow, defaultCellColumn), Sheets("Active Product Catalog").Range("E:AK"), countryIndex(i), False) = "Yes" Then
                    'If Not Purchaseable, Change Color
                    countryCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
                If Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(cellRow, defaultCellColumn), Sheets("Active Product Catalog").Range("E:AK"), countryIndex(i), False) = "Yes" Then
                    'If Purchaseable, Change Color
                    countryCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
                End If
            Else
                If Application.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(cellRow, countryCell.Column), Sheets("Active Product Catalog").Range("E:AK"), countryIndex(i), False) = "Yes" Then
                    countryCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
                End If
            End If
        'Else
        'End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `defaultCellColumn=4` but use undefined variable `defaultCell` in your first two formulas. It is a good idea to use `Option Explicit` at the start of your module - then this gets caught when you compile.

Not sure about the third error but your `countryIndex` array goes all the way to 35 which is more than the number of columns in `E:AK`. Recognize that `VLOOKUP` uses column *offset* relative to the range, not *absolute column*, for the third parameter (so 2=F in your case, and 35=AM which is outside of the range you specified and will throw an error.)

Answer (score 0):

`Data type mismatch` error can be handled using the below method.

```
On Error Resume Next
Result = Application.VLookup(Cells(cellRow, countryCell.Column), Sheets("Active Product Catalog").Range("E:AK"), countryIndex(i), False)
If Result = "Error 2042" Then
    Result = "Nothing Found"
Else
    MsgBox Result
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```